# Oracle Database table for keeping web-app user's activity log

Tags: database, oracle, size, storage

I want to keep a full activity log of all actions made by a user from my web application. I have made several tables to help me do this and came across this question:
I need to store a relatively long text in just one column. Is this a good practice and is using **varchar2(2000)**, for example, a good practice too? I will have about one-two million records.

Comment: as soon as you make it 2000 chars, someone will open a bug that they can't store 2001 characters. consult your data model. what sort of text is going in there? is there a BUSINESS definition for this data? is it valid to want to store say...a million characters there? if so, consider a CLOB instead

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no it's not going to happen, because the web application is forbidding the users from entering more characters even in the front-end. I am asking the question in terms of: "is it a good practice to keep such column data for one million records?".

Comment: famous last words, everyone starts thinking no one will access their data outside of their application...you can always bump it up to 4k or 32k later. and shouldn't be an issue. problem is what you're doing with that data later - do you need keyword indexing? look at oracle text for example

Comment: @thatjeffsmith well I am new in Oracle universe and it's a job task. The most important thing is to keep track of everything from the users. So, for example, we have a "Comments" section in the Web-app. We need to store these comments in the database. Daily traffic is about 200 comments. Every comment has about 400 characters allowed. It's just an example, but as I've said I am new and it's a task ha-ha...

Comment: I think you're on the right track, if you see on avg 400, to store as 2k sounds reasonable. there are always edge cases though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, as far as storage space in the database goes this is fine. VARCHAR2 fields only take as much space as the actual data requires so if you only have 100 characters only the space required for those 100 characters will be used in the database.

On the other hand, when you **read** the data out of the database you may encounter issues. Because the program reading the data doesn't know how many characters are actually stored in each row it may allocate the full 2000 characters of space so that when the data is transferred from the database to the program's memory the space is available. For two million records that would be about four gigabytes of storage if all those rows were read into memory simultaneously.

Gripping hand, you may not have much choice. If you need to store characters strings of this length in a column go ahead and make the column `VARCHAR2(2000)` (or 4000, or up to 32K in newer versions of Oracle). Just be aware of the potential issues and don't be shocked if memory issues occur. Remember, hardware is cheap - programmer time is expensive.

(Incidentally - the "one hand/other hand/gripping hand" meme comes from the book "The Mote In Gods Eye", by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle. If you're a science fiction fan and you haven't read it, you should :-).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have an idea, when the data becomes about 1 million records, I will transfer it to log files and release Oracle and the server from it. Thanks for the book it will be a nice weekend if I find it in my local market. Btw I am still a newbie in Oracle, so if my ideas are crazy or stupid, it's from lack of experience.

Comment: 1M records is NOTHING...it's a good start, and it will work, scale just fine in your oracle db.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562176/unique-constraint-without-index/56563844#56563844) I posted a minor rant about "hardware cheap / programmer expensive". It's a (kinda) humorous 20-second read, but I think I make a good point - at the insanely low cost of hardware (I'm so old I remember when computers cost **real money** and IBM ruled - so shoot me...) fixing performance problems with hardware is more cost effective than having developers spend days and weeks making things run faster. Companies don't do that because nobody "sees" salary-and-benefit costs.

Comment: @BobJarvis so what was missing from my answer? ;)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: **bolded** and *italicized* text. And CAPS - need LOTS and LOTS of CAPS! :-)